# TransactionTooLargeException while copying file Android

Tags: java, android, copy-paste

My aim is to browse a file and copy it, and paste it in a other folder.

To browse the file I have used Intent as shown below

```
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
       intent.setType("*/*");
       intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "DEMO"), 1001);

       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
           if (requestCode == 1001) {
               Uri currFile = data.getData();
            }
        }
```

Now I want to copy the file for that I have to get file real path from URI.
(I am passing file real path to java FileInputStream )

To convert Uri to real path I did as shown below

```
   public static String getPath(Context cx,Uri uri) {

    String filePath = "";

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT ){

        String wholeid = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        String id = wholeid.split(":")[1];
        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
        Cursor cursor = cx.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }else{
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = cx.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return uri.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            filePath = cursor.getString(idx);
        }

    }
    return  filePath;
}
```

If the file is more than 10kb it is giving TransactionTooLargeException.

My question is how can I browse and copy a file and paste in a folder without getting TransactionTooLargeException.

Is there any good method to do that.

Comment: "To convert Uri to real path I did as shown below" -- that will not work for most Android devices. "If the file is more than 10kb it is giving TransactionTooLargeException" -- please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have posted whole code used to convert uri to real path. It is working for me for small size files.